# how to calculate Davies Bouldin from clustering methods in rapidminer?

Tags: cluster-analysis, rapidminer

I want to cluster data without k-means. for example I prefer to cluster with DBSCAN or support vector clustering.

So I need evaluating performance of clustering with Davies Bouldin metric but I don't know how to calculate Davies Bouldin in Rapidminer for DBSCAN or Support vector clustering.

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator `Cluster Distance Performance` allows the Davies-Bouldin validity measure to be calculated. This requires a cluster model containing the cluster centroids to be passed to it which means approaches like Dbscan and Support vector clustering cannot be used with it because they do not produce cluster centroids.